# NLP: vectorizer/metric to upweight absence of frequent terms

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, natural-language, tf-idf

I'm doing hierarchical clustering of documents in a corpus; there are words that occur in almost all the documents.

To define document similarity,  I've used `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer` and `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`.

The results look reasonable; but it occurs to me that the absence in a particular document of a word that occurs in almost all documents ought to be very significant, whereas in my approach I gather that idf makes the presence or absence of that word relatively insignificant.

Before I reinvent the wheel (and possibly poorly):

Is there an established vectorization/metric that would give a large increment in similarity to two documents in each of which a very common word was absent — and a large decrement in similarity to two documents only one of which included the very common word?

Comment: Often people just remove common terms. Look for "stop word lists", but removing too many words can also degrade the performance, so it is a bit of a tradeoff.

Comment: Using stop words would take me in the opposite direction - presence or absence of a word in the stop list would have no effect on document similarity.